# installation issues with musrffit using CERN/ROOT

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, root, bashrc

I successfully installed root. After this, I set the environment variables (in .bashrc) as follows

export ROOTSYS=/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install
export PATH=$ROOTSYS/bin=:$PATH

Then I activated the changes by source.bashrc
Next when I am trying  to install  musrfit by following command in the directory /home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install

$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/muonspin/musrfit.git

$ cd musrfit

$ mkdir build

$ cd build

$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ROOTSYS -Dnexus=1

**CMake Error at /home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/cmake/ROOTConfig.cmake:173 (message):

ROOT component MathMore not found

Call Stack (most recent call first):

CMakeLists.txt:74 (find_package)**

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

---

I installed cmake in the directory
/usr/local/bin/cmake

Is there any connection of this cmake path to musrfit?

In advance, I appreciate it.

Comment: Try installing gsl-bin package using apt install gsl-bin and try again.